# Handle differently formatted timestamps in a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file that contains data with the following timestamp format: "%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S". I have created the code to parse these datetimes with pandas in python:

```
mydateparser = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S")
df = pd.read_csv(filename, parse_dates = [3], date_parser = mydateparser)
```

The problem is that every data point at the beggining of a day is formatted like this "%Y-%d-%m", so instead of being "2018-01-07 00:00:00" it is just "2018-01-07". These data points of course give me this error:

> ValueError: time data '2018-01-07' does not match format '%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S'

How could I resove this? Can I use an alternative parser or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are the only variants, you could just define a parser instead of using lambda:

```
def my_date_parser(d):

    try:
        result = pd.datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S")
    except ValueError:
        result = pd.datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%d-%m")

    return result


df = pd.read_csv(filename, parse_dates=[3], date_parser=my_date_parser)
```